# Clarification of the Heroku CLI + Github Workflow?

Tags: node.js, git, github, heroku, heroku-cli

I am struggling to understand git & heroku. I have created a nodejs server, pushed it to my github account. I've made a few changes, pulled again, pushed again, and so on.

Now I decide to deploy it to heroku.

Here are herokus instructions:

[image]

I have the heroku cli, but I skipped step 2, since I already have everything set up on github (maybe this is what I am doing wrong? am I not supposed to mix heroku & github?). Then comes step 3:

```
git push heroku master
```

What exactly does this do? It pushes my repo to heroku? where does this `heroku` branch come from? And: Do I have to change anything to my normal workflow? Can I just do a normal `git push` to my repo on github? I am running into errors here constantly, and I think it's because I don't seem to fully understand the workflow / how these things are supposed to work together.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the problem was that I **skipped the second step**.
Especially where it says:

```
heroku git:remote -a ....
```

So I had both heroku and github connected, but would only push to heroku - so my github would be behind.

What I should be doing, if I want both connected, is to push to github first, and then do:

```
git push heroku main / master
```

After having done this, I do not run into this problem anymore.